# Call a method from a previous story board

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have the mainstoryboard + viewcontroller

When I press a button on the mainstoryboard it will show another storyboard.

When I press a button in the new storyboard I want to call a function of the mainstoryboard.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: You should look into your design and figure out *why* you need to call a method on a viewController that is no longer visible. Maybe this function can be pulled out into separate class.

Comment: Using protocols is the usual pattern for communication with controllers lower in the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the storyboard and instantiate a viewController from it like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
```

But if you require a function that contains the context of the previous view controller, you should keep a reference to it and just call your methods directly from there. You can also use the `presentingViewController` property to access the view controller that started the modal presentation. Or if using a navigationController you can use the `viewControllers` property to access previous viewControllers in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Abizem gave me the right tag to search for.

'Protocols'.

I found a very good explanation here on stackoverflow.

Look there:
[How to access a previous story board.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Just have a look at the answer of Matt Price. Very nice explanation!